# EF Core does not recognize composite key

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm getting this primary key error when trying to startup my .net core application. I have the exactly same composite key structure with another entity that works fine. What am I missing with this one?

**Exception:**
System.InvalidOperationException: 'The entity type 'DispatchOrders' requires a primary key to be defined. If you intended to use a keyless entity type call 'HasNoKey()'.'

**Main classes** (both with Id as key)

```
public class Order : BaseEntity
public class Dispatch : BaseEntity

public class BaseEntity
{
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime? ModifiedDate { get; set; }
        public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
        public string ModifiedBy { get; set; }        
}
```

**Composite key class**

```
    public class DispatchOrders
    {        
        [ForeignKey("DispatchId")]
        public int DispatchId { get; set; }
        public virtual Dispatch Dispatch { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("OrderId")]
        public int OrderId { get; set; }
        public virtual Order Order { get; set; }
    }
```

**Composite key class fluent**

```
public DispatchOrdersMap(EntityTypeBuilder<DispatchOrders> entityBuilder)
        {
            entityBuilder.HasKey(o => new
            {
                o.DispatchId,
                o.OrderId
            });

            entityBuilder
            .HasOne(e => e.Dispatch)
            .WithOne()
            .HasForeignKey<Dispatch>(e => e.Id);

            entityBuilder
            .HasOne(e => e.Order)
            .WithOne()
            .HasForeignKey<Order>(e => e.Id);
        }
```

**Table**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DispatchOrders](
    [DispatchId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [OrderId] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_DispatchOrder] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [DispatchId] ASC,
    [OrderId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[DispatchOrders]  WITH CHECK ADD FOREIGN KEY([DispatchId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Dispatch] ([Id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[DispatchOrders]  WITH CHECK ADD FOREIGN KEY([OrderId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Order] ([Id])
GO
```

Comment: It looks like you are trying to map a many-many join table. The mapping structure is changing in .NET5. Which version of EF are you using? If your using 3.x, try mapping from the direction of the child tables rather than the join table.

Comment: Also, when stuck with mappings you can't figure out, I recommend trying to scaffold the database on a test project and see how the scaffolding does it for your tables to learn and then update your code as appropriate..

Comment: It seems that you want to create a many-to-many relationship. You only need to configure their composite key. If the names match, efcore will automatically generate a foreign key, so you can delete the configuration of your one-to-many relationship and efcore will automatically configure it. I tested that this method is feasible.